# How can I select data with the same date time from data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am analyzing telemetry data using panda. Data saved in HDF5 files. Of course data has times when they have saved. So my question is how to extract data with the same datetime from dateframe(even seconds)? 
For example data looks like this:

```
943             Power.PDM_1__PDM_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:17:50    8.965
944                    Power.PDM_2__PDM_Current_A 2019-06-13 00:17:50    0.174
945  Power.BCM0_Battery_Interface_Plate_Temp_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20   19.829
946      Power.BCM1_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20   79.146
947      Power.BCM2_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20   81.280
948                  Power.BCR0__Array_Current_mA 2019-06-13 00:18:20  561.000
949            Power.BCR0__Array_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20    5.920
```

So if data is 2019-06-13 00:18:20, I expect only this data:

```
945  Power.BCM0_Battery_Interface_Plate_Temp_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20   19.829
    946      Power.BCM1_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20   79.146
    947      Power.BCM2_Battery_Cell_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20   81.280
    948                  Power.BCR0__Array_Current_mA 2019-06-13 00:18:20  561.000
    949            Power.BCR0__Array_Temperature_degC 2019-06-13 00:18:20    5.920
```

I have this code so far:

```
file = pd.read_hdf('KazSTSAT5.h5', mode = 'r')
#reads HDF5 file

df = pd.DataFrame (file)

#converts UNIX type data to Usual datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

timestamp = df.iloc[0, 1]

time = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: With [`Boolean Indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) most likely

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the date column indexed.

```
ts = pd.Timestamp
print(df.query('time == @ts("20190613T001820")')
```

Comment: I did not get what I expected. Can you look at code, please?

Comment: Have you tried executing the above after the conversion of unix timestamp to date format? Also, I would suggest to query the data frame using unix timestamp itself.

Comment: 1547251207.0
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ch_name, time, value]
Index: []